# How to properly protect SQL injection in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a controller and I'm wondering if Rails has already parsed the params and prevented SQL injection or not. Here's what my controller looks like:

```
class V1::JobsController < ApplicationController
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods
  include ActionController::Serialization
  before_action :set_job, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authorize_api_key, only: [:create]

  # GET /jobs
  def index
    status = (params[:status]) ? params[:status] : 'pending'
    @jobs = Job.where(publisher_id: params[:publisher_id], status: status)

    render json: @jobs
  end

  ...
end
```

Is this safe as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code is safe.

For example don't use something like this:

```
Project.where("name = '#{params[:name]}'")  # DON'T USE
```

[For more information](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection)